# Delete child table records based on column size in parent table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a scenario like this :
I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT(DEPT_PK NUMBER NOT NULL,DEPT_NAME VARCHAR(10),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_PK NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,DEPT_PK NUMBER(4),EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(50),ADDRESS VARCHAR2(200));
CREATE TABLE SALARY(SALARY_PK NUMBER NOT NULL,EMP_PK NUMBER(4),net_salary number(5,2));
```

Now i want to delete the record from dept table and whose dept_pk size is 4 and modify the table's dept_pk size to 3.

Note that emp table has dept_pk as foreign key and salary table has emp_pk as foreign key.

I need to write a pl/sql procedure or sql query for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `dept_pk size is 4` ? Do you want to get rid of all PK's that require 4 digits (i.e. everything above 999) ? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward - create a procedure that issues the deletes in the right order and finally uses native dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) to change the dept_pk column. Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 1st to delete from `SALARY`:

```
delete from SALARY where EMP_PK in
(
  select EMPLOYEE_PK
  from EMPLOYEE
  where DEPT_PK in
  (
    select DEPT_PK from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4
  );
);
```

Then from `EMPLOYEE`:

```
delete from EMPLOYEE
where DEPT_PK in
(
  select DEPT_PK from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4
);
```

And now from `DEPT`:

```
delete from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4;
```

**EDIT :** if you really want to use PL/SQL, you just have to enclose the following code into `begin` and `end` for one shot execution:

```
begin
delete from SALARY where EMP_PK in
(
  select EMPLOYEE_PK
  from EMPLOYEE
  where DEPT_PK in
  (
    select DEPT_PK from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4
  );
);

delete from EMPLOYEE
where DEPT_PK in
(
  select DEPT_PK from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4
);

delete from DEPT where length(DEPT_PK) = 4;
end;
/
```

or create a procedure for re-usability: add `create or replace procedure proc_name is` before `begin`.

Comment: thatnks for the ans wer but i want a pl/sql for this. Could you please help me out with this.

Comment: ,thanks for the help. But i need a generaL solution FOR this scenario.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? What is missing in my solution ?

Comment: I mean to say i want a procedure which takes input from the user as column name, table name and new value and then delete records from the parent and child table.

Comment: You should have clearly said it in your description then. This is much more difficult (recursive dependency handling + dynamic SQL), I don't want to spend too much time any more so I'll stop there.